# Using jQuery/Ajax to Open Various URLs and with Various Parameters

Tags: jquery

I construct a column of tables using a PHP do-while loop. Typically there are between 1 and 8 tables. In each table I have three clickable images each of which opens a different URL. I need to pass four parameters to the URL, one of which (room_id) will be different in each table.

In simplified form the table is coded like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="centleft">
            // Some content here
        </td>
        <td>
            <form name="PriceData" id="PriceData_<?php echo $room_id ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="hid" id="hid" value="<?php echo $hid ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="room_id" id="room_id" value="<?php echo $room_id ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="ArrDate" id="ArrDate" value="<?php echo $ArrDate ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="DepDate" id="DepDate" value="<?php echo $DepDate ?>">
            </form>
                <img src="../images/euro.png" class="eurotip bookajax">
                <img src="../images/pound.png" class="poundtip bookajax">
                <img src="../images/dollar.png" class="dollartip bookajax">
        </td>
        <td class="sr">
            // More content here
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="prices_<?php echo $room_id ?>" style="display:none"</div>
```

The jQuery script I have after some assistance from @daremachine is:

```
$('.eurotip').on('mouseover click', function(){
var room = $(this).closest('td').find("input[name='room_id']").val();
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'book1_ajax.php',
        data: $(this).closest('td').find('form').serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            $("#prices_" + room).html(result).slideDown(2000);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that the script doesn't work on the first table, yet it does work on all subsequent tables. Nothing I tried would solve this neatly so I've had to work around it by adding an invisible dummy table above the do-while loop, so then all the following tables work properly. It's a crude hack, but it seems to work.

```
<table style="display:none"><tr><td><form></form></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: $(table[name='PriceData'] input[name='room_id']) must be quoted string and it should work fine if you change table to form. And call europtip, poundtip and dollartip ajax is same? with same values?

Comment: daremachine. Form v table was a finger problem on my part. The comma at the end of the line was another error. It should have been a semi-colon. So I can now create the variable "room" but it always has the value of the first table. I understand why (all tables have the same name for the form, and all the clickable images are the same class). But how do I differentiate them?

Comment: change data in your ajax for $(this).closest('td').find('form').serialize(), it should be what you want

Comment: That's the magic ingredient, daremachine! Thanks. I'm just ironing out a few other issues and then I'll update my original post to show the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need call one listener to multiple selectors you separate them with [comma](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Or make listener body like standalone function and call it in multiple listeners.

```
const myAjaxFnc = function() {
  ...some ajax
}

// listeners
$('#img').click(myAjaxFnc);
$('#div').click(function() {
  alert('hi');
  myAjaxFnc();
});
```

To solve your problem with ajax data you should to change `data` in your ajax for

```
$(this).closest('td').find('form').serialize()
```

**It says:** from element where I clicked find up in DOM tree first `TD` element and than find from in DOM tree down first form element. (you can specify selector ofc, or can change td to tr for row)

This ensure so your context will be only in `TD` element and it can not be mixed with other table TR rows or TD columns.

Comment: I've just updated the original post to show that I have reached a part solution. The $(this).closest seems to work on all tables except the first one.

Comment: @TrapezeArtist Problem probably will be here $('.eurotip').on('mouseover click', function(){.. try to change for $(document).on('mouseover click', '.eurotip', function(){

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you. That one didn't work though.

Comment: For some reason that I don't understand, the script won't work on the first table/form. So for the moment my workaround is to put in a dummy table and form like this:
<table style="display:none"><tr><td><form></form></td></tr></table>

Comment: Its any magic because your scripts are ok. It seem like your html can be broken. It have to work for all.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I worked through the HTML very carefully and can't see anything wrong with it.